# Instalación de Neatbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

tengo un problema para instalar Neatbeans,les muestro el error que me sale.
Les agradezco su ayuda.

[image: The specified installation folder is not empty]

Comment: El mensaje dice que el folder de instalación que has especificado no está vacío. Parece que ya tenías una instalación previa de Netbeans y/o del JDK. Prueba a desinstalar todo con Uninstall y si no funciona bórralo manualmente. Por cierto, no sé por qué le pusiste la etiqueta `html` a esta pregunta.

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a intentarlo.

Comment: podrías compartir que tienes en esa capeta para poner una respuesta en caso de que alguien tenga el mismo poblema?

Answer (score 1):

En realidad este mensaje indica que Netbeans trata de instalarse en un folder que contiene archivos,  que es:

```
C:\Program Files\Netbeans 8.2
```

Probablemente tienes una instalación, o trataste una instalación, si tienes una instalación puedes desinstalarla, es recomendable realizarlo desde el panel de control en la opción agregar o remover programas, seleccionar "agregar o remover programas", seleccionar "NetBeans IDE 8.2" y dar clic en "remover".

o simplemente cambia el directorio de instalación, por ejemplo:

```
C:\Program Files\Netbeans82
```

Y procede la instalación.

Answer (score 0):

Concuerdo con borrar todo e instalarlo de nuevo, pero hasta donde se hay dos maneras de instalarlo,la primera es con el instalador que incluye el JDK y se instalan los dos al mismo tiempo,pero si los tienes separados es decir netbeans  y JDK primero debes instalar el JDK y despues el netbeans si no te causara un error.

Comment: Borrar e instalarlo de nuevo no es una solucion!!!

Comment: No lo intenten!, borrar todo es demasiado general, no creo que se refiera a borrar el sistema operativo, el firmware y la existencia de quien tenga este problema. Borrar TODO no creo que sea la solución aunque asi lo parezca.

Comment: me referia a desintalar todo lo referente a netbeans para hacer una instalacion limpia

Answer (score -1):

En MX linux me sirvió ir donde estaba instalada otra versión de NetBeans > borrar carpeta, luego se instaló normalmente.